# Riak performance with multiple secondary indexes(2i)

Tags: riak, secondary-indexes

I'm doing a plan for a system and I'm considering changing the database from a relational model to a KV with extra feature like Riak. Most of the functionality for the requirements can be modeled in KV without any problem but for those corner cases I'm having some trouble. I've been reading about the 2i backend for Riak and it look pretty handy. There are some question I couldn't found any answer.

What kind of performance degradation or change in memory usage should be expected with increasing number of 2i per entry?

How many 2i should be used per entry?

Can a 2i change is value and what are the consequences for Riak performance if any(ex. A field that stores last activity)?

Comment: 2i are handy indeed, but take into account that they are much less reliable than KV and can't be considered an equivalent of RDBMS indexes (since you've mentioned a relational model). 2i are usually good if you can tolerate outdated or lagging results.